# Weak convergent without completeness implies strong convergence

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, normed-spaces, weak-convergence

I want to know if the following holds without completeness:

In a normed linear space $H$, $x_n$ is weak convergent to $x$, and $\lim_{n\to\infty} \|x_n\| = \|x\|$ then:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\|x_n-x\|=0$$

---

I have a previous question, that is answered with regard to Hilbert spaces, but can this hold without completeness?

With the rules I have seen proven for Hilbert spaces, it isn't very hard. But can it be done without being in a Hilbert space.

Comment: Completeness is irrelevant, $H$ and its completion $\tilde{H}$ have the same dual. [Pedantically, the restriction to $H$ gives an isometric isomorphism from $\tilde{H}'$ to $H'$.]

Comment: This is not true in general Banach spaces. Just take $H = C([0,1]\cup [4,5])$ and $f_n (x)= nx$ on $(0,1/n)$, $f_n (x)=1-n(x -1/n)$ on $[1/n,2/n)$ and $f_n =0$ everywhere else on $[0,1]$ and finally $f_n \equiv 1$ on $[4,5]$.

Comment: This was also briefly discussed [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/14150).

Comment: @DanielFischer: Why is it relevant having same duals here? As far as I know this is due to having a plain scalar product only. No need of results related to Riesz if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @Freeze_S The point is that since the duals are the same (modulo the canonical identification), it is irrelevant whether $H$ is complete or not, weak convergence $x_n \rightharpoonup x$ means the same in $H$ as in $\tilde{H}$. [Of course if $H$ isn't complete, there are lots of sequences that converge - weakly or strongly - in the completion but not in $H$, but here we assume that the (weak) limit belongs to $H$.] We don't need an inner product for the result, uniform convexity suffices (possibly even less).

Comment: @DanielFischer: How do you prove it then in case there's no scalar product available? For scalar product one obtained $\|x-x_n\|^2=\|x\|^2+2\Re\langle x,x_n\rangle+\|x_n\|^2$. There one had $l\in\mathcal{H}'$ for $l(z):=\Re\langle x,z\rangle$.

Comment: @Freeze_S Without loss of generality, assume $\lVert x\rVert = 1 = \lVert x_n\rVert$. Pick $\lambda \in H'$ with $\lVert\lambda\rVert = \lambda(x) = 1$. Given $\varepsilon > 0$, the uniform convexity says there is a $\delta > 0$ such that $\lVert y\rVert = \lVert z\rVert = 1$ and $\lVert y+z\rVert > 2(1-\delta)$ implies $\lVert y-z\rVert < \varepsilon$. For large enough $n$ we have $\lambda(x+x_n) > 2(1-\delta)$, hence $\lVert x+x_n\rVert > 2(1-\delta)$, and thus $\lVert x-x_n\rVert < \varepsilon$.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Great, thanks!!! :)

Comment: Wow I just logged in right now, weird haha.